# UIReturnKey not showing in UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad

Tags: ios, xcode, uikeyboardtype

Very simple question: How do I add a UIReturnKey to a UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad? If I assign the `textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;` to the textfield, nothing happens (as it normally would given any other keyboard type).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` does not have return key for iPhone but you can add your own buttons using

```
@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView
```

property of `UITextfield`